# What would Skynet do after it defeat humans?

Tags: the-terminator-series

What is ultimate goal of Skynet? It started WW3 to eliminate humans, so what will it do after the last humans die?

It not like in Matrix, as Skynet has human-independent sources of power supply. So it really doesn’t need humans.

Comment: ***Skynet will finally rest... and watch the sun rise on a grateful universe.***

Comment: What would the humans do after defeating Skynet?